# How to display user avatar in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, avatar

I'd like to know how to display a user avatar in Drupal 7. 
I want to display the avatar in full size and as the thumbnail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
$user_item = user_load_by_name($username); // or user_load( $user->uid )
print theme('user_picture', array('account' =>$user_item));
```

Comment: for imagecache sizes (thumbnail etc.):

global $user;
$imgUrl = $user->picture->uri;
theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'STYLE', 'path' => $imgUrl));

Answer (score 1):

When I use  the user picture is linked to the user profile. I have set my user images to be displayed as thumbnails. I'd like to link the user picture to the full sized picture and display them using lightboxII. It seems to be a very easy task but I couldn't figure out yet how to do it.

Comment: That is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable User profiles in the account settings (admin/config/people/accounts) and then you can display them in templates using $user_profile:-

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php/7

The user-picture.tpl.php template will let you override how it is output.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you provide some lines of code for better understanding, I'm a new to Drupal.

Comment: OK, for example, in your node template (node.tpl.php) you can include <?php print $user_picture ?> where you want the profile picture to appear. If your doing this within a comment template (comment.tpl.php) then use <?php print $picture ?> instead (not sure why, but they're different).

Comment: I get the error: `Notice: Undefined variable: user_picture in include() (line 230 of C:\xampplite\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\themes\MyBartik\templates\page--teams.tpl.php).` when use this code `<?php print $user_picture ?>` in page--teams.tpl.php

Comment: It won't work in a page template as the page doesn't have a user associated with it like a node or comment. Check out http://drupal.org/node/190815 which lists all the available core templates and the variables you can use in them.